# Issue in Form Validation - Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have included validation for my sign up page, but when I load the sign-up page 
Error appears. It should show errors after clicking submit button
What i need to do?

My sign-up page

```
  <% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
  <div class="notice">
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @user,validate: true do |f| %>
<% if !@user.valid? %>
 <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= f.label("Name:") %>
<%= f.text_field(:user_name, class: "form-control") %></br>

<%= f.label("Email Address:") %>
<%= f.text_field(:email_id, class: "form-control") %></br>

<%= f.label("Password:") %>
<%= f.password_field(:password, class: "form-control") %></br>

<%= f.label("Confirm Password:") %>
<%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, class: "form-control") %></br>

<%= f.submit("Register",class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:20px" href="/login" >Login</a>
<% end %>
```

My model where I have included my validations

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :reviews
    has_secure_password 

    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :user_name, :presence => true, :on => :create, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email_id, :presence => true, :on => :create, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
    validates :password, :presence => true, :on => :create,  :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
    validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true
end
```

Controller

```
    def new
    puts "****Inside New Method******"
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
   puts "****Inside create Method******"

   @user = User.new(user_params)
   puts @user.user_name
   if @user.save

    puts "** USER DETAILS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY****"
    flash[:notice] = "Registration successful, please login"
    flash[:color] = "valid";
    redirect_to "/login"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Invalid Form"
        flash[:color] = "invalid"

   end

 end
```

When I load the page, Error appears before clicking the submit button
I have included :on => :create but it doesn't work

please help!!

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Are you trying to use client side validation gem? or just server side validation (normal/default) ?

Comment: I have posted controller code. Not client side validation, I am using normal validation

Answer (score 0):

`if !@user.valid?` on the form might be causing this. This is not necesarry, since you are only checking if the record is valid in the controller, just before saving your record.

You should also add `render :new` when the record could not be saved, otherwise you get a view missing error.

Comment: If i remove !@user.valid also its throwing error, because of empty object @user causes @user.errors.any? is true

Comment: But if you haven't submitted the form yet, there shouldn't be any errors.

Comment: Not . part of answering this question, but you should consider using Devise gem for this type of business.

Comment: Before submitting, I have initialized to @user = User.new so it would be empty so its throwing error. Using Devise is my last option, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Open rails console and try to manually create the user. Is it create or not?

eg:

```
user = User.new(username: "test", email_id: "test@test.com", password: ...)
```

and check the validation by using

```
user.valid!
```

you will get the error message if validation fails. If no error then save it

```
user.save!
```

Comment: My Concern is error message is displaying when the page loads, actually error should be displayed while clicking on submit button

Comment: so are you able to create record manually on rails console? Have you checked it?